# What is the JNDI name should I use to lookup for a remote interface deployed in websphere using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, ejb, websphere, spring-remoting

I have a remote interface deployed in websphere 8.5.5 and I want to look up for this in spring boot application. I have made similar interface in my spring boot as common interface `RMI` I also used `SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean` but the proxy returned is `null` and it was throwing `null` pointer in `proxy.invokeMethod()`

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

    private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory";
    private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "corbaname:iiop:localhost:2809/NameServiceServerRoot";

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public static AdminService adminService() {

        Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL);

        SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean factory = new SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setJndiEnvironment(jndiProps);
        factory.setJndiName("java:global/[AppName]/[ModuleName]/ejb/[BeanName]![RemoteInterface]");
        factory.setBusinessInterface(AdminService.class);
        factory.setResourceRef(true);
        AdminService proxy = (AdminService) factory.getObject();
        try {
            proxy.invokeMethod();
        }catch(RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return proxy;       
    }
}
```

Now it's throwing this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AdminService' defined in class path resource [...Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [...AdminService]: Factory method 'adminEJBService' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [global/[AppName]/[ModuleName]/ejb/[BeanName]![RemoteInterface] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [global].
```

Answer (score 0):

You must replace everything in `[]` with the actual name, so not `[AppName]`, but `MyApp`, etc.  If not sure, you can determine the exact lookup string by looking in `SystemOut.log` file of the WebSphere 8.5.5 server for the message `CNTR0167I`.  For example, the actual message would look like this:

```
CNTR0167I: The server is binding the javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome interface of the Management enterprise bean in the mejb.jar module of the ManagementEJB application.  The binding location is: java:global/ManagementEJB/mejb/Management!javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome
```

Comment: I know for sure everything in `[]` it should be replaced by the actual values I'm just doing this cuz I don't want to expose the info. Also I'm very sure that all these names are correct because I'm getting them from App deployed on **Websphere**. @Tracy